# Сохранить данные в .csv

Tags: qt, csv

Сохраняю данные из двух векторов в .csv файл таким образом(вектора имеют тип double):

```
    void MainWindow::save_csv()
{

QString filename = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,
                                           tr("Save csv"), ".",
                                           tr("csv files (*.csv)"));
QFile file(filename);
if (file.open(QFile::WriteOnly|QFile::Truncate))
{
QTextStream stream(&file);
for(int i=0;i<=for_step_x.size();i++)// для звездной величины
{
stream << for_step_x[i]<<"\t"<<","<<for_step_y[i]<<"\n";
}
file.close();
}
QMessageBox::information(NULL,"show","Данные успешно сохранены");
}
```

При открытии вордом элементы строк записываются как и должно быть(через табуляцию с запятой). При открытии же экселем все данные записаны в один столбец. Пробовал и без табуляции, сделав разделителем только ",", эксель тоже распознает как один столбец. Как это исправить?

Comment: попробуйте разделять столбцы только ';' (точка с запятой)

Comment: @gil9red нет, так тоже не выходит. может попробовать переводить элементы векторов в стринг? хотя и так должно работать, вроде

Comment: @bronstein87 , а если вручную создать csv-файл, накидать туда чисел через запятую, а затем попробовать открыть в экселе? Мало ли... Ну и в качестве ещё бреда установку кодировки и флаг `QFile::Text` добавить. Тоже мало ли...